# 'undefined' is not an object on load map

Tags: google-maps, javafx

I´ve been unsing this code for several months, but suddenly doesn´t works.
I´m triying to load a map and show some markers on it with positions of a database. The link to the database and the return of the query are ok.

JavaFX file:

```
public class MapController  implements Initializable{
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FinalizadosController.class.getName());


    @FXML
    Button changeConductorButton;

    @FXML
    ComboBox<String> conductorComboBox;
    ConductorGestor mConductorGestor = new ConductorGestor();
    private List<String> nombreConductoresComboList;

    @FXML
    WebView mapaWebView;

    WebEngine engine;

    PosicionGestor mPosicionGestor = new PosicionGestor();
    double lat;
    double lon;

    @FXML
    HBox fechaHBox;
    private DatePicker fechaDatePicker;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        fillComboBoxConductor();

        fechaDatePicker = new DatePicker(new Locale("es", "ES"));
        fechaDatePicker.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        fechaDatePicker.getCalendarView().todayButtonTextProperty().set("Today");
        fechaDatePicker.getCalendarView().setShowWeeks(false);
        fechaDatePicker.getStylesheets().add("/view/DatePicker.css");

        fechaHBox.getChildren().add(fechaDatePicker);

        final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("googlemapscriptvictor.html");
        engine = mapaWebView.getEngine();

            lat = 22.209938;
            lon = -1.727726;


        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        System.out.println("ESTADO CAMBIADO: " + newState);
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {


                            mostrarTodosLosConductores();
                        }
                    }
                });

        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
        mapaWebView.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                // intentionally do nothing
            }
        });
    }

    protected void mostrarTodosLosConductores() {
        try {


            LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "Inicio mostrarTodosLosConductores() " );
            System.out.println("MOSTRAR CONDUCTORES");
            for(String condNombre : nombreConductoresComboList) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "condNombre: " + condNombre);
                Posicion p =  mPosicionGestor.selectPosition(condNombre);
                LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "p: " + p.getIdPosicion());
                if(null!=p){
                    if(p.getIdPosicion()!=0){   

                        if((p.getxPos()!=0)&&(p.getyPos()!=0)){
                        engine.executeScript("addInfoBulle('"+ condNombre +"',"+p.getxPos()+","+p.getyPos()+",'"+p.getmFecha()+"','"+"direccion"+"');");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            engine.executeScript("goToLocation("+lat+","+lon+");");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, UtilsVictor.exceptionStacktraceToString(e));
            UtilsVictor.showAvisoScreen("ERROR", e);
        }
    }






    public String getLocationInfo( double lat, double lng) {


        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        String json = new String();
        try {
            json = readUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat + ","+lng + "&sensor=true_or_false" );
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject location;
        String location_string = new String();
        try {
            //Get JSON Array called "results" and then get the 0th complete object as JSON        
            location = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0); 
            // Get the value of the attribute whose name is "formatted_string"
            location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }



        return location_string;
    }

    private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }

    }



}
```

the thml file, the key is putted ok in my code here putted xxxx

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Java-Buddy: Google Maps</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxx"></script>
<style>
#mapcanvas {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%
}
</style>



</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mapa Situación Chóferes</h1>
    <div id="mapcanvas">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.map = new google.maps.Map(document
                    .getElementById("mapcanvas"));

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.78266856772762, -1.976816946635381);
            var Options = {
                zoom : 9,
                center : latlng,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            //creamos el mapa
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"),
                    Options);


            var arrayPuntosRuta = [];
            var markersArray = [];
            function borrarPuntos(){
                arrayPuntosRuta = [];
            }

            function addPosicionARuta(x,y) {
                var puntoRuta = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
                arrayPuntosRuta.push(puntoRuta);
            }

            function showRuta(puntosRuta) {


                var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path : arrayPuntosRuta,
                    geodesic : true,
                    strokeColor : '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity : 1.0,
                    strokeWeight : 2
                });

                flightPath.setMap(map);

            }

            //Creamos el marker que se va a ir mostrando

            function addInfoBulle(nombreconductor, x, y, hora, direccion) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position : new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
                    map : map,
                    draggable : false,
                    //icon: carMarkerImage,
                    title : "tit",
                    autoPan : true

                });

                var contentString = '<div id="content"><p>Conductor:  <strong>'
                        + nombreconductor
                        + '</strong></p>    <p> Hora: <strong>'
                        + hora
                        + '</strong></p><p>Dirección:<strong>' + direccion + '</strong></p><p>Velocidad:<strong>Km</strong></p></div>';

                var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content : contentString
                });
                markersArray.push(infobulle);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                    infobulle.open(map, marker);
                });
            }

        function goToLocation(x, y) {
                alert("goToLocation, x: " + x + ", y:" + y);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
                map.setCenter(latLng);
            }           
        </script>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the fail:

```
[INFO] 2018-11-21 21:23:24,555 - controller.FinalizadosController -90966 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR controller.FinalizadosController  - netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.executeScript(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(Unknown Source)
at controller.MapController.mostrarTodosLosConductores(MapController.java:162)
at controller.MapController$1.changed(MapController.java:128)
at controller.MapController$1.changed(MapController.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$600(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFinishLoading(Native Method)
at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.access$1300(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader$6.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why is happening this? and suddenly...

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: Looks a lot like it can no longer find the scripts `addInfoBulle` and `goToLocation` in method `mostrarTodosLosConductores()`. Probably because can no longer read the script `googlemapscriptvictor.html`. Check errors where you access or load this script, for example after this call `final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("googlemapscriptvictor.html");`

Comment: But it had been working several months...

Comment: Something has changed right? So you need to do some debugging.

Comment: sorry, i was in a work travel, at the end the problem where in the api key, now you have to pay for using maps...

Comment: If your use level is low, you don't have to pay. When you sign up, you get credit for $200 or something like that. You can read it up.

Comment: I´ve created it, and after read i will not have to pay. But now I have anothe Exception [netscape.javascript.JSException: Error: The Google Maps JavaScript API does not support this browser.] ....

Comment: Ok I suggest edit your question, and just show the error you are now getting, together with the code line that is causing it. Remove anything not relevant. Then, If no one has already done so I will take a look later today.

Comment: At the end the code is fine, after making the account in Google, but now doesn´t works on java 7, only java 8 and higher, but i need to use java 7 due to other program requeriments. Is possible to use Java 8 withouth install it? Packaging on the app for example?